# cout is not a member of std, and other issues regarding c++

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

Allow me to preface this by saying that I do have  included (also applies to string, endl, and quite literally everything doesn't work); my IDE is showing no errors as far as syntax goes; and I cannot understand why this issue is happening? It works fine in one of my other C++ code samples I wrote.

So I am trying to make a small game, bulls and cows. My main code looks as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BullsAndCows.h"



using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

int main()
{

    string userInput = "";
    bool playAgain = false;

    int gameDiff;

    constexpr char * GREETING = "Welcome to Bulls and Cows! Please enter the difficulty level: (1) Easy, (2) Medium, (3) Hard";

    cin >> gameDiff;

    do
    {
        BullsAndCows *bc = new BullsAndCows();
        bc->playGame(gameDiff);

    } while (playAgain);


    constexpr char * INFORMATION = "Total Word Length  is: ";

    //Introduce the game.

    cout << GREETING <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My header:

```
#ifndef BULLSANDCOWS_H
#define BULLSANDCOWS_H



class BullsAndCows {

public:


    void playGame(int gameDiff);


};

#endif
```

Finally, my BullsAndCows.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BullsAndCows.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

void BullsAndCows::playGame(int gameDiff) {

    string wordGuess = "";
    string secretWord = "";
    int numBulls = 0;
    int numCows = 0;
    int numGuesses = 0;

    switch (gameDiff)
    {

    case 1: {
        numGuesses = 30;

        secretWord = "Hello";

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

            numBulls = 0;
            numCows = 0;

            cout << "Word Length to Guess Is Five, you have " << numGuesses << " guesses remaining" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your word guess";
            cin >> wordGuess;

            for (int j = 0; j < wordGuess.length; j++) {
                if (wordGuess.at(j) == secretWord.at(j)) {
                    numBulls++;
                }
                else if (secretWord.find(wordGuess.at(j)) != -1) {
                    numCows++;
                }
            }

            cout << "Bulls: " << numBulls << endl;
            cout << "Cows: " << numCows << endl;

            if (numBulls == secretWord.length) {
                cout << "YOU WIN!" << endl;
                break;
            }

        }

        break;
    }
        case 2:
            numGuesses = 20;
            break;
        case 3:
            numGuesses = 10;
            break;
    }

}
```

Errors I am getting as "cout is not a member of std", cout symbol cannot be used in a using declaration. Before that I was using "using namespace std" and that would return errors like "BullsAndCows" is not a namespace or class (if it is not a class, then I must be a martian). Also something about a missing ";" before userInput for example in my main.cpp code; which makes no sense as there is nothing that is missing that. I am using VS2017. Why is C++ such an annoying language to work in?

Comment: not sure why you have using std::cout instead of just using namespace std;

Comment: have you tried putting #include "stdafx.h" at the very top of file?

Comment: that one was related to the { at the start of case 1. I have no idea why it is throwing all of these errors. It makes 0 sense really.

Comment: You'll really need a [mcve], but from the code posted here, main.cpp cannot see a definition for `std::string`, so add a `#include <string>` to main.cpp

Comment: Is this a feature of Visual Studio rather than C++ itself? It's ages since I have done anything with it, but anything before `#include "stdafx.h"` tends to be ignored due to automatic precompilation. What happens if you move `#include <iostream>` after  `#include "stdafx.h"`?

Comment: stdafx.h is automatically generated by Visual Studio as one of its default includes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the directive

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

before any other include directives.

Comment: Spasibya. 100%. My head has just made a China sized hole through my desk. I will keep that in mind for the future when I make more files/projects. I will accept your answer once the timer allows me to.

Comment: I recommend not using precompiled headers.  You should measure how much build time it saves you and determine if precompiled headers are worthwhile.