# Visual Studio precompiled header prevents compiler from recognizing std::cout

Tags: visual-studio, precompiled-headers

I'm trying to build a DLL (but it works the same for static library) in Visual Studio 2017; this is my complete source.cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"

void f() { std::cout << "I'm in f!\n"; }
```

When I compile, it complains that

```
error C2039: 'cout': is not a member of 'std'
```

If I take out stdafx.h, its complaint is

```
fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?
```

There's got to be a way to compile functions that use `std::`!

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` must be the first include. The compiler ignores every line above that. This is a feature of MSVC precompiled headers. I am sure that there are many duplicates of this.

Comment: Sure couldn't find it! Happy to have the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cout is not a member of std, and other issues regarding c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904130/cout-is-not-a-member-of-std-and-other-issues-regarding-c)